# "I think it strange that .." -- is the phrase correct or does it miss a verb before 'it'?

Tags: verbs, ellipsis, syntax

> *I think it strange* that there is no one on the street at this time of
>   the day.

In the above sentence, I think, a verb is missing; and should be corrected as;

> *I think it **is** strange* that there is no one on the street at this time of
>   the day.

or,

> *I think it **to be** strange* that there is no one on the street at this time of
>   the day.

At the same time, I think, it could be correct as it is.

"I think it strange that .." -- is the phrase correct or does it miss a verb before 'it'?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The original sentence is correct.  "I think it strange that ...", "I find it strange that ...", and "I consider it strange that ..." are all acceptable constructions.

The accepted answer to this question:

https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/40795/omitting-is-like-in-i-think-it-strange

has an excellent discussion of this usage.

Your second and third sentences are also technically correct, but they sound a little awkward compared to the first sentence.  In general, an English sentence tends to benefit from the omission of unnecessary words.