# Think somebody/something + adjective

Tags: usage

I think the following sentence is incorrect

> He thinks her **a fool**.

Because in such constructions after **somebody adjective** is used, and the sentence should be

> He thinks her **fool**.

Am I right?

Comment: I believe the first one is right, however sounds awkward. The second one is not correct.  I would go with, "He thinks she is a fool"

Comment: "Fool" isn't an adjective. You could say "He thinks her foolish."

Comment: Possible duplicate of ["I think it strange that .." -- is the phrase correct or does it miss a verb before 'it'?](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/198621/i-think-it-strange-that-is-the-phrase-correct-or-does-it-miss-a-verb-bef)

Comment: There's nothing wrong with the first sentence. The second sentence is ungrammatical.

Comment: @Jason the above sentence is same as.    I thought her kind and generous, and it is correct